# GCP deployment fails on "Updating service"

Tags: mysql, asp.net, google-app-engine, .net-core, google-cloud-platform

I have asp.net core application hosted on GCP App Engine. When I try to deploy the application it fails on last step:

> Updating service [name] (this may take several minutes)...   ...failed

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy>blablabla.wm.1

The exception stack trace show that service running in background couldn't find MySQL table (that table obviously exists).

my app.yaml file:

```
service: XXX
runtime: custom
env: flex
automatic_scaling:
  max_concurrent_requests: 80
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: XXX
  memory_gb: XXX
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: "XXX:XXXX:XXXX=tcp:3306"
```

It looks like the application is deployed properly despite the error. This is the only error and backgroud service desn't throw any exceptions at later point. In fact it works properly and can connect to the database.

My guess was that maybe GCP is checking health while the application is not connected do database. So I tried to add `liveness_check` and `readiness_check` to app.yaml and configured dedicated /healthcheck endpoint in my application but it didn't make any change.

Any ideas how to fix it and what might be a cause?

Comment: When you get this error, you can take a look at crash.log in the [Cloud Console Logs Viewer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview) (Logging -> Logs) for your specific service / version which will usually tell you exactly what happened. But I would like you to try specifying the number of instances to a maximum of two, this can be done either through manual_scaling or max_num_instances while using automatic scaling to 2 (automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 2)/(manual_scaling:
  instances: 2) in your app.yaml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploying app with new version fixed the issue

Comment: You can mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: How did you deploy new version?